# Что за курьи ножки у избушки?

Tags: этимология

*Прочитал с статью в Википедии, и простой вопрос этимологии названия для меня стал совсем запутанным. Все разговоры о сущности этой избушки как портала между мирами мертвых и живых я опускаю. Все это безумно познавательно, но к этимологии прямого отношения не имеет.*

Если очень кратко. Вики объясняет все вполне логично, через пеньки, на которых в болотистой местности славяне ставили хозяйственные и культовые постройки (усыпальницы своего рода). Но, если разбираться внимательно, в Вики и массе других источников приводятся как единое две (а то и три) взаимоисключающие версии.

1. Курьи (а то и "курные") ножки - никакого отношения к курам не имеют, а только созвучны с ними. Пеньки эти сами по себе назывались "куром", возможно потому, что их окуривали.
2. Пеньки эти делались из стволов деревьев с частично обрубленными корнями (это предохраняло от гниения), ставились они по саамской технологии на камни

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(с) Вики.

Тут сходство именно с куриными ногами очевидно. Совершенно исключаю мысль, что в каком-то саамском языке могла быть параллельная с русским игра слов (кур-куры), то есть, если предположить саамскую версию "ножек" или даже прямую кальку с саамских, то они именно курьи, куриные - пусть и названы так только по внешнему сходству.

Ну и наконец возможна какая-то экзотическая смешанная версия, объясняющая само слово "кур" (пеньковые стропила) через переосмыслением исходно куриного смысла, а потом обратное преобразование в курьи. Но в это верится мало.

***Итак, какие доводы в пользу первой или второй версии? Что первично у избушкиных ножек - кур или куры?***

====

Добавлено. *Я априори не рассматриваю версии, что избушка могла реально стоять на **куриных** (в прямом смысле) ногах. Физика исключает, да и здравый смысл тоже. Всё это - сказочные переосмысления, интересные в рамках фольклористики, но никак не поиска исходного значения, этимологии.*

Answer (score 3):

**Курьи ножки ― это куриные ножки.**

У В. Проппа: ..**.избушка имеет вид животного**. Особенно часто имеют животный вид двери.  Что дверь избушки кусается, т. е. представляет собой рот или пасть.  Эта хата-зверь постепенно теряет свой звериный вид. Наибольшей сопротивляемостью обладают двери: они дольше всего сохраняют вид пасти.   **Думается, что и птичьи ноги есть не что иное, как остаток зооморфных столбов, на которых некогда стояли подобного рода сооружения.**

Этим же объясняются **животные, охраняющие вход в нее**. Мы здесь имеем то же явление, которое наблюдается в процессе антропоморфизации бога-животных. То, что некогда играло роль самого бога, впоследствии становится его атрибутом (орел Зевса и т. д.).

То же имеем и здесь: то, что некогда было самой хатой (животное), становится атрибутом хаты и дублирует ее, выносится к выходу.

[5. Избушка на курьих ножках | e-reading.club](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/46789/34/Propp_-_Istoricheskie_korni_Volshebnoii_Skazki.html)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**В этой теме нет одного ответа, всё перемешано: быт, погребальные обряды, сказочное осмысление реальной действительности.**

1) **Курными избами** назывались избы, топившиеся «по-чёрному», то есть, не имевшие печной трубы. Использовалась печь без дымохода, называвшаяся «курной печью» или «чёрной». Дым выходил наружу через двери и во время топки висел под потолком толстым слоем, отчего верхние части бревен в избе покрывались копотью.

2) В древние времена существовал **погребальный обряд**, включающий в себя обкуривание ножек «избы» без окон и дверей, в которую помещали труп.
Избушка на курьих ножках в народной фантазии была смоделирована по образу славянского погоста-маленького домика мертвых. Домик ставился на опоры-столбы. **В сказках они представлены как куриные ножки тоже не случайно.** Курица-священное животное, непременный атрибут многих магических обрядов. [Секреты русской избы | vk.com](https://vk.com/wall6650016_5728)

3) Неясно, какой смысл в необрубленных корнях: мне кажется, что столбики для жилого дома для устойчивости надо всё-таки в землю закапывать. Значит, на картинке погребальное сооружение?

4) А как вообще в Древней Руси защищали дерево от гниения? Разные способы существовали [Защита древесины народными средствами. Исторический экскурс. | защита-древесины.рф](http://%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B.%D1%80%D1%84/otzyvy/76-zashita-drevesiny-narodnymi-sredstvami.html)
К примеру, смолой, дегтем  можно было пропитать дерево в подземной части, для наземной части использовалось разогретое льняное масло. Иногда дерево обжигали паяльной лампой (?), но вот была ли технология окуривания дымом?
У Даля "куръ" - это деревянные стропила, не только пеньки-столбики. Может быть, их окуривали?

Comment: А кто такой Пропп? И как тогда быть с фоткой из Вики? Не, копипастить кочующие из разных источников сомнительные версии - не комильфо. Их и без того навалом. К тому же там нет ничего по части этимологии.

Comment: Комильфо. И удивительно то , что Вы не знаете Проппа, а курьими ножками интересуетесь. Пропп - первый авторитет по сказкам, автор двух известных трудов" "Морфология сказки" и "Исторические корни волшебной сказки"

Comment: Ничего удивительного. Я интересуюсь этимологией, а не сказками. Просто лениво серьезно разбирать все, что этот сказочник наговорил. К этимологии не имеет ни малейшего отношения. Это - фольклор, а он сам по себе вторичен.

Comment: Так речь идет об исторических корнях сказки, а  этимоло́гия  - это историческое языкознание. Пропп как раз и рассказывает  о реальной жизни людей,  отраженной в сказках  (быт, обряды, поверья и т.д.). Поэтому не спешите с оценками, зачем лишний раз пренебрежительно отзываться как  об известных ученых, так и о ваших коллегах, которые отвечают на Ваши же вопросы, вот это точно не комильфо.

Comment: Вы путаете.  1. Я вообще не интересовался сказками, ни корнями, ни верхами 2. При чем тут жизнь людей, если у Проппа речь идет о фантастическом переосмыслении?  3. У меня тут нет коллег и я не отзывался неуважительно о присутствующих. Если Вы приняли это на свой счет, готов извиниться.

Answer (score 1):

Я стока-многа букаф в вапросе ниадалела...

Можно, я сразу перейду к

[**«ДОМИКУ МЁРТВЫХ»**](http://paranormal-news.ru/news/izbushka_na_kurikh_nozhkakh_jazycheskij_domik_mertvykh/2013-05-29-6975),

минуя версии с курями и обрубками, м?

Ножки у избушки - курные, то есть изба отапливается печью, не имеющей трубы.

> ...Древний погребальный обряд включал в себя обкуривание ножек «избы»
>   без окон и дверей, в которую помещали труп или то, что от него
>   осталось.
>
> ---
>
> ...«Домик мертвых» ставился на опоры-столбы. В «домик мертвых»
>   московиты складывали испепеленный прах покойного (как и хозяйка
>   избушки Баба-Яга всегда хочет засадить Ивана в печь и изжарить его
>   там).
>
> ---
>
> ...Куриные ноги - всего лишь «ошибка перевода». «Курьими (курными)
>   ножками» московиты называли пеньки, на которые и ставилась изба, то
>   есть домик Бабы-Яги изначально стоял всего лишь на закопчённых
>   пеньках. Скорее всего, эти пеньки обкуривались, чтобы по ним не
>   проникали в «домик мертвых» насекомые и грызуны.

P. S.

[Этимология слова КУРНОЙ](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9)

> Происходит от гл. курить, далее из праслав., от кот. в числе прочего
>   произошли: ст.-слав. коурити, коурити сѩ (др.-греч. καπνίζεσθαι), укр.
>   кури́ти, болг. ку́рна «зажигаю», сербохорв. ку́рити, ку̑ри̑м,
>   словенск. kúriti «топить, отапливать», чешск. kouřit «курить, дымить»,
>   словацк. kúriť, польск. kurzyć, kurzę, в.-луж. kurić, н.-луж. kuriś.

Значительно менее авторитетный этимолог глаголет:

[Этимология слов КУРЕНИЕ, КУРИТЬ](http://www.literra.listbb.ru/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=1104)

> Корень КУР- со значением «дымить» образовался от сложения трёх
>   двусогласных корней. В подробном пересказе эта конструкция вот что
>   означает: во время священного ритуала подкладывать в огонь ветки
>   определённых растений, для того чтобы они издавали нужный приятный
>   запах. Я могу предположить, что это был можжевельник, но доказать, что
>   это так – совершенно невозможно. Скажу даже более того: трудно
>   настаивать на том, что это вообще были ветки; это могли быть и
>   какие-то коренья. Дело в том, что биконсонантный корень WR, который
>   участвует в этой конструкции, это всё-таки в первую очередь корень, а
>   значение «ветка» является более поздним, хотя оно потом почти
>   полностью вытеснило значение «корень» в большинстве индоевропейских
>   диалектов.
>
> Итак, получается такая картина: костёр не простой, а ритуальный – это
>   жёсткое предварительное условие, а в этот костёр добавляют для
>   создания нужного запаха некие ветки или коренья.
>
> Вот это и вся этимология.

P. P. S.

["ВОЗДУШНЫЕ" ЗАХОРОНЕНИЯ](http://paranormal-news.ru/news/ostorozhno_shamanskie_mogily/2014-01-07-8321)

> ...Не всем сегодня известно, но далекие предки европейских славян и их
>   соседи когда-то, еще до погребальных костров, хоронили своих усопших
>   подобным образом. Отсюда и идут русские народные сказки, например, о
>   царевне, спящей в хрустальном гробу, подвешенным на цепях. А если
>   вспомнить под этим углом описание «избушки на курьих ножках» и «бабы
>   яги – костяной ноги», у которой «нос уперт в потолок, голова – в
>   стену, ноги – в дверь», то становится ясно, что речь именно о
>   воздушном погребении. Тогда понятен и суеверный страх, охватывающий
>   добрых молодцев перед случайно обнаруженной и вроде бы безобидно
>   лесной «избушкой».
>
> Для сооружения арангаса саха (а также эвенки, юкагиры, эвены) выбирали
>   четыре рядом стоящих дерева, отпиливали им вершины и на высоте
>   примерно двух метров соединяли перекладинами. На эти перекладины и
>   устанавливался гроб, представлявший из себя выдолбленную колоду из
>   двух половинок цельного и достаточно толстого ствола. Специальные
>   фиксаторы и клинья плотно прижимали верхнюю часть колоды к нижней и
>   неподвижно закрепляли весь гроб на помосте. Иногда, чтобы корни
>   деревьев меньше прогнивали, их обнажали, снимая сверху дерн и
>   действительно превращая их в «курьи ножки». Образцы таких захоронений
>   можно увидеть в Музее Дружбы под открытым небом в с. Соттинцы
>   Усть-Алданского улуса.

[ИЗБУШКА НА КУРЬИХ НОЖКАХ - ЭТО... ГРОБ!](http://www.maximonline.ru/longreads/get-smart/_article/mythological-archetype-of-the-fairy-tale-characte/)

> Мифологический и сказочный образ необычной избушки взят из реальности.
>   В древности умерших хоронили в тесных домиках — домовинах
>   (по-украински гроб до сих пор называется «домовина»). В сказках
>   подчеркивается теснота избушки-гроба: «Лежит Баба-яга, костяная нога,
>   из угла в угол, нос в потолок врос». Гробы-домовины ставили на очень
>   высоких пнях с выглядывающими из-под земли корнями — казалось, что
>   такая «избушка» и правда стоит на куриных ногах. Домовины ставились
>   отверстием, обращенным в противоположную от поселения сторону, к лесу,
>   поэтому герой просит избушку на курьих ножках повернуться к нему
>   передом, к лесу задом.
>
> ---

Итого.

Куры отдыхают. Строеньице (окуренное) - на столбиках-опорах, иногда, из-за проступающих корней, *напоминающих* курьи лапы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да перейти-то вы можете, но вопрос был не в том, чтобы найти в интернете одну из известных версий, а в том, чтобы разобраться в этимологии, объяснить сем эта версия лучше другой, которую я тоже приводил. Или как-то непротиворечиво объединить обе.... Sibylia вон так вообще настаивает, что ножки реально куриные, она так буквально Проппа поняла... И тоже без всякого обоснования выбора версии.  И как я буду лучший ответ выбирать?

Comment: Мне приведённая версия показалась весьма убедительной, потому и привела: окуренные ножки-столбики - защита от мелкой ползающей и шмыгающей гадости. Другое жутко заинтересовало (при изучении цитируемого источника): кто такие МОСКОВИТЫ?! О_о Аж два вопроса задала: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2508664-moskovity-eto-slavjanizirovannye-finno-ugry-aziaty-turancy-trete.html#answer7376759 и http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2508646-ja-ne-ponjala-statja-kto-takie-moskovity-o-moskvichah-ili-o-moskovitah.html

Comment: Настолько убедительной, что вы даже не стали читать мой вопрос, где я её упоминал?

Comment: *Московиты* - жители страны под названием Московия.

Comment: Ага, Московия. Но ведь это тоже миф. И я дополнила ответ.

Comment: Московия - миф????

Answer (score 1):

Версии, видимо, всё-таки придётся объединить.Корень "кур" оказался многозначным. Вот Курск - совсем от другого "кура"- омонима "курья" - "речной залив, заводь, старое русло рек, а также угодье, прилегающее к ним»(Словарь русского языка XI-XVII веков).Но в этом же словаре есть и "Ношка" (Ножка) - "узкая полоса земли, вдавшаяся в чужие земли». Значит, чисто теоретически «избушка на курьих ножках» может означать маленький деревянный дом, расположенный на узкой полосе земли возле старого русла между своей и чужой землёй.

А ещё есть иранск.(перс.)«khuros» — «петух»;  славянск.«кур» — «прах, пыль» или же «дым», либо тот же "петух", заимствованный из персидского.

Пушкин не придумал фразу, он воспользовался готовым фразеологическим оборотом, услышанным от няни. Она вполне могла рассказывать об избушках на курьих ножках - временных небольших постройках в лесу (лабазах) на сваях-пеньках, обкуренных (кур-дым) от насекомых и грызунов и от гниения в сырости болот(процесс обжига брёвен тоже называли курением). Кстати, в старой Москве одна из деревянных церквей была установлена на такие пеньки и называлась «Никола на курьих ножках». Эта церковь упоминается в летописях с 1639 года, её разрушили только в 1934 году.

Во многих русских сказках фигурирует «избушка на курьих ножках», где обитает Баба-Яга.Историки и специалисты по фольклору считают, что ответ на этот вопрос следует искать в древней языческой культуре захоронений в обрядовых "домиках". Очевидно, «домики мертвых» играли еще и культовую роль. Древние финно-угры (когда-то территории верхней Волги и Москвы-реки населяли финно-угорские племена) видели в них «порталы», ведущие в подземное царство, куда уходят усопшие. Ведь и для сказочных героев путешествие в волшебную реальность зачастую начинается именно с избушки Бабы-Яги, вход в которую находится со стороны леса (тёмный лес символизирует смерть - свет/тьма). Чтобы войти в избушку, герой должен попросить её «повернуться к лесу задом, а к нему передом». Тогда открывается вход в царство мертвых или в мир сказочных существ.

А со значением птицы "кур - петух" тоже есть связь. Курьей ножкой называли ещё развилку трех дорог, исходящих из одной, как на лапке курицы. Избушка, стоящая в середине этой развилки, потому так и называлась.

Пушкин объединил всё (у него всегда фантастика соединяется с реальной жизнью): его избушка  на курьих (курных) ножках - сваях стоит на развилке трёх дорог в тёмном болотистом лесу между своей и чужой землёй как портал для перехода в мир сказочных существ (царство мёртвых).

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но я не вижу причин для какого-то объединения версий. То, что корень многозначный, это и так понятно. Но ни из вашего текста, ни вообще из чего-либо, не видно, что  "куры" как-то могли быть связаны с куром (стропилами) или с курением (не очевидно даже, что одно с другим связано). Вариант, что это о разных избушках речь идет, тоже совершенно не аргументирован. Очень уж странное совпадение.  А что еще можеь быть основанием для объединения? Народная этимологий? Она возможна, но вторична, как вы понимаете.

Comment: Третья версию, с "куреношкой", я, конечно, тоже видел, но она совсем уж надуманная. Пушкин - это был аргумент против буквального понимания Проппа, не рассматривается сам по себе.